# Codepage related problems with MySQL++

Tags: c++, mysql, codepages, mysql++

Code:

> mysqlpp::Query acc_query = connection->query("SELECT * FROM accounts;");

The following code produces:

> _Gfirst = 0x00c67718 "SELECT * FROM accounts;ээээ««««««««юоюою"

As in Visual Studio debugger. It appears to cause my query to fail with weird results.

Has anyone else encountered it?

Answer (score 1):

It's [best to use UTF-8](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/doc/html/userman/unicode.html) encoding with MySQL.  Code pages are a Windows-centric pre-Unicode concept.  Your use of them instead of Unicode probably explains why you're having problems.  While it's possible to make MySQL — and thus MySQL++ — work with Windows-style code pages, you shouldn't be doing that in 2010.

If you *are* using Unicode, it's probably UTF-16 encoding (Windows' native encoding in the NT derivatives), which again explains a lot.

Convert all string data into UTF-8 form before sending it to MySQL, and configure MySQL to use UTF-8 encoding in its tables.